# Simultaneous multiplication of three matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

This is a very silly question... I know. But I really can't figure out how to implement the attached formula. Here is an example:

For input data:

```
L_i =

    0.1022         0         0
         0    0.1656         0
         0         0    2.7321
```

and:

```
U_i =

    0.7514    0.3104    0.5823
   -0.6513    0.4901    0.5793
   -0.1056   -0.8145    0.5704
```

How to obtain the following results?

```
1,1 = (2.7321*(+0.7514)*(+0.7514) + 0.1656*(+0.3104)*(+0.3104) + 0.1022*(+0.5823)*(+0.5823))
1,2 = (2.7321*(+0.7514)*(-0.6513) + 0.1656*(+0.3104)*(+0.4901) + 0.1022*(+0.5823)*(+0.5793))
2,1 = (2.7321*(-0.6513)*(+0.7514) + 0.1656*(+0.4901)*(+0.3104) + 0.1022*(+0.5793)*(+0.5823))
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
    A = U_i*diag(flipud(diag(L_i)))*U_i'
```

Then the matrices L_i and U_i contain the [eigenvalues and eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix), respectively, of A.